# mention collection when saving a schema

Tags: mongoose

Is there a way to dynamically mention the `collection` name when saving a `document` in `mongoose`?

Eg.

Instead of calling `someSchema.save()`, I want to call `someSchema.save(someNonHardcodedDynamicallySelectedCollectionNameMaybeFromVariableValue`).